# Run Javascript in “Visual Studio Code” from W10 and Bash

Tags: bash, visual-studio-code, windows-10

I know how to do this in MACOS and in W10 if I were using the "usual" setups.

My problem is that I installed npm and node through Bash in W10 so:

> which npm & which node
>   /usr/bin/npm
>   /usr/bin/node

Under this circumstances I don´t know how to set the runtimeExecutable path:

> "runtimeExecutable": "/usr/bin/npm"

I get this error:

> attribute runtimeExecutable does not exist (/usr/bin/node)

Is what I am trying to do even possible?
Or maybe I should set up everything the W10 way?

Answer (score 0):

Well, in the end I just installed node and npm with the windows installer and set the Git bash as my default shell for the Visual Studio Code terminal.

Everything works smoothly although I still have npm and node installed in the Ubuntu bash shell.

They are two isolated environments.

Cheers!